# How to use the Node-red-dashboard template node send-function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, node-red

I'm trying to create a controller for some rgb-leds in node-red. The idea is to make a clickable color palette from where the user selects the color. I think this could be done with the node-red-dashboard ui-modules template node. However I can't get the template node to send the selected color. The only example I found is this:

```
<md-button ng-click="send({payload: 'Hello World'})">
    Click me to send a hello world
</md-button>
```

Which doesn't work for my situation and doesn't tell much about the send-function usage(at least for me). So would it be possible to do it somewhat like this:

```
<md-button ng-click="send(getPixel(event))">
        Click
</md-button>

<script>
    getPixel = function(event){

        //Get the pixel color based on event.x and event.y

        return "{payload: 'calculated-response'}";
    }
</script>
```

Or can i use the send-function in somewhere else than in ng-click? 
Btw the color selecting is under control and I don't need help with it. Many thanks for everyone who tries to help :)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it, since `getPixel` method isn't exposed on `$scope` on controller.

Instead call `send` function and `$event` object to it, the from `send` function call `getPixel` method.

```
<md-button ng-click="send($event)">
    Click
</md-button>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.send = function(event){
    getPixel(event);
    //do other Awesome code
}
```

Other way would be just make available getPixel function on a $scope by doing below.

```
$scope.getPixel = getPixel;
```

By adding above line inside a controller would make whatever you wrote working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this unfortunately doesn't work. It throws a reference error: `$scope is not defined`. The `send()` method is already made in node-red or node-red-dashboard and based on the only example (which is in my question), it takes the messages payload as parameter.

Comment: Inject `$scope` in controller function